# Referring to parent class in Java

Tags: java, class, this

I want to know if it possible to use This() To reffer MotherClass, Calling My motherClass A and executing it from my Child Class B. witch one is correct ?

```
Class A { A(){ System.out.println("hello");}

Class B extends A { this() ;  B(){System.out.println("World");}}

OR 

class A {
 Class B { this(); B(){System.out.println("World");} }
}
```

I want when to Call Class B it show Me (HelloWorld);

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What do you mean by _calling My motherClass A and executing it_? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: `super.xxx()`, not `this`

Comment: Please post a compilable code. And also clarify the question a bit more. Currently I can't understand the question.

Comment: I think you're looking for `A.this`, but proper, compilable code would help overcome the language issues...

Comment: Use "this" to refer to members of an instance of that class, use "super" to refer to immediate parent classes.

Comment: I'm gonna edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: @Chlebta Use Netbeans, should help you with all the cool built-in autocomplete functions.

Comment: Why it got to be a mother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `this()` is meaningless unless you are calling it in a constructor and which means to call a constructor overload for this current class (if one exists). Please see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for the details on this. To call a super class's methods, again use the `super` keyword.

Incidentally, your code still doesn't compile. Please understand that you can't be careless when coding -- the compiler won't let you, and neither should you be when creating and posting code for questions here.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a file - parent.java

```
public class parent {
    parent(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

---

### Create another file - child.java

```
public class child extends parent {
    child(){
        super();
        System.out.println("World");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        child c = new child();      
    }
}
```

==============================

Creating an instance of child class will first call the parent class constructor and then the child class constructor; resulting in the o/p you are looking for.